# Laravel 5.3 Send database notifications

Tags: laravel, notifications, laravel-5.3

when `admin` adds a new appointment for a `user`, database notification should be created for all `admins` as well as the assigned `user`. And When viewing the notifications all the `admins` should see all notifications while users should see only notifications assigned for them.

```
public function submitAppointmentForm(Request $request){

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'respond' => 'required',
        'user2_status' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
    }
    else
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $appointment = new Appointments();
        $appointment->project_list_id = $request->project_id;
        $appointment->respond = $request->respond;
        $appointment->user2_status = $request->user2_status;
        $appointment->date = $request->appointment_date;
        $appointment->assigned_to = $request->assign_to;
        $appointment->user2_note = $request->user2_note;

        $appointment->assigned_by = $user->user_id;
        $appointment->added_by = $user->user_id;
        $appointment->save();

        $assign_to = User::where('user_id', $request->assign_to)->first();

        Notification::send($assign_to, new NewAppointmentNotification($request));

        return response()->json(['success'=>'Successfully added']);
    } 
}
```

with above code notifications only added for assigned `user`. not for `admins`

how to add admins also when sending notifications

```
Notification::send($assign_to, new NewAppointmentNotification($request));
```

**UPDATE :**

Thanks to `Dees Oomens` i got it working i did a small modification as per my  requirement

```
$assign_to = User::where('user_id', $request->assign_to)->first();

$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($q){
                $q->where('name', 'admin');
            })->get();

$users->push($assign_to);

Notification::send($users, new NewAppointmentNotification($request));
```

Comment: How do you identify admins? Is there an attribute on the `users` table with something like `is_admin` or is it done via relations?

Comment: i have used entrust for Roles and Permissions. I can get admins but do not know how to pass to send($assign_to,$admin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get all admins. You're using entrust so I'm not sure how what role name you've used, but my best guess would be:

```
$users = User::with(['roles' => function($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'admin');
}])->where('id', '!=', $user->id)->get();

$users->push($assign_to);

Notification::send($users, new NewAppointmentNotification($request));
```

Now all users in the `$users` array will get the notification. And the `$users` array contains all admins (but not the current authenticated admin) and the user which is `$assign_to`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll check this today and let you know

Comment: Your solution works fine. I did a small modification just get users by role. Thanks for the help. cheers